# Alternative function of json_build_object() in PostgreSQL 9.2

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to build the object to JSON using the function json_build_object() which is not working in PostgreSQL 9.2.I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to find the alternative of json_build_object in 9.2.json_build_object() the function is added from the 9.4 version.

```
-- Function: queue_event()

-- DROP FUNCTION queue_event();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION queue_event()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
 
DECLARE
data json;
notification json;
 
BEGIN
 
-- Convert the old or new row to JSON, based on the kind of action.
-- Action = DELETE? -&gt; OLD row
-- Action = INSERT or UPDATE? -&gt; NEW row
IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
data =row_to_json(OLD);--row_to_json
ELSE
data =row_to_json(NEW);--row_to_json
END IF;
 
-- Construct the notification as a JSON string.
notification = json_build_object(
'table',TG_TABLE_NAME,
'action', TG_OP,
'data', data); ---- Alternative to this function in 9.2 whereas in 9.4 version it is working fine.
 
-- Execute pg_notify(channel, notification)
PERFORM pg_notify('q_event',notification::text);
 
-- Result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
RETURN NULL;
END;
 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION queue_event()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Are you aware that Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)? You should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Does it work with `row_to_json()` and `select into`?

```
select row_to_json(x) into notification
from (values(TG_TABLE_NAME, TG_OP, data)) as x("table", action, data)
```

Comment: row_to_json() is worked in 9.2 version.Where as json_build_object() function is not working in 9.2 version. The above statement has worked.Thanks..